# How to compare a readonly field

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing my own class to mimic the `PointF` class in .NET.

```
public class PointD
{
    public static readonly PointD Empty;
    public double X, Y;
    // ... Other functions
}
```

In my example, how do I use the field `Empty`? When I compare it, is it something like:

```
PointD myPoint;
if(myPoint == PointD.Empty) // do something
```

Comment: You need to override the == operator, != operator, and the Equals method.

Comment: Take a look at the PointF source code to see how Microsoft does it: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Advanced/PointF@cs/2/PointF@cs

Comment: you can override the operator, or you can use a nullable type too `PointD?` then you can `if(myPoint == null)`

Comment: @bto.rdz No, PointD by virtue of being a class is already nullable. PointF is not comparable to null because its a struct (value type).